# Using predefined html in new posts

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I hope to make my life easy by doing this. I have 2 types of posts. On the first post I have a table and each post from the respective category will fill a table row. 
I will show you how a posts of mine looks like the following:

```
<tr><td class="expand footable-first-column">SA Spurs</td>
<td class="away">Miami Heat</td>
<td class="time" style="">
<p id="time3" class="time" title="Hours : Minutes"></p>
</td>
<td class="bskt footable-last-column" style="">
<div id="bskt"> </div>
</td>
<td style="display: none;">
<div id="progame">
<span id="gmatch">GAME MATCHUP</span>
<table id="lb" cellspacing="0"> // I have another table whitin a table row //
<tr id="rt">
<th id="at"><span class="rank" title="position">2</span>SAS</th>
<th id="promatchup">vs</th>
<th id="ht"><span class="rank" title="position">1</span>MIA</th>
</tr>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 </tbody></table>
 </tr>
```

The table's head is predefined in the custom page template that's why I only use the  in my posts.

I was wondering if it is possible to have my tds/divs/p look like inputs in the post textarea that are predefined with the classes and respectives IDs so I would only type in new content everytime I want to add new content to the table.

I've been looking into CPTs but I either didn't get it right or it cant be done with it.
Other method I can think about is to hack the textarea displayed in my dashboard, but there's a drawback from this, I also have a 2nd post style and I dont know what to do.

Hope I've been clear enough. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) :

```
function td_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<your markup>' . $content . '</your markup>';
}
add_shortcode( 'td', 'caption_shortcode' );
```

And in post : `[td] blabla [/td]`

Answer (score 0):

The initial content for new posts is provided by [`get_default_post_to_edit()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_default_post_to_edit/) function and you can tinker with filters in it to provide customized content:

```
$post->post_content = apply_filters( 'default_content', $post_content, $post );
```

However personally I consider this approach a little fragile, might be worth looking into metaboxes to build more robust interface and separate data from markup. Otherwise next time you will suddenly need to adjust markup you will have to edit all the posts.